# Creating iFrame with content cross origin

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I'm trying to **create** an empty iframe fill it with some html-code (here: "Hello World")
using javascript.
The script file is hosted at domain `a.com` and loaded from a website at `b.net`.

All the other js code works but when I try to set the iframe's content, I get an cross origin error.
Is there a propper workaround which works?

```
var node = document.createElement("iframe");
node.setAttribute("border", "0px");
node.setAttribute("sandbox", "");
node.setAttribute("id", "preload");
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].appendChild(node);
node.contentWindow.document.open();
node.contentWindow.document.write("Hello World");
node.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I don't want to _get_ content, I want to _set_ content. So the just created iFrame has no content...

Comment: But is this realy cross origin? Since the iFrame does have no src attribute, how can it have an origin?

Comment: @VDWWD If the question is a dublicate, why does removing "sandbox" then solve the problem? Actually the cross origin error is just misleading...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "sandbox" does actually block the access to the document. Removing "sandbox" solved the problem.